# Dependent and independent Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading  the Linear Algebra. I have doubt on dependent or Independence of vectors.

What I understand is following

1.Vectors that doesn't span a space are independent.

2.If they span a space that means they have some combination in their own space and I will get the less Vector.Can I say they are dependent ?

Am I going into the right direction while understanding the linear algebra. Are these points  correct. Please rectify if I am not correct.

I am just novice in Linear algebra.

Comment: What do you understand to be the meaning of “span a space?”

Comment: @AnuragRag Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

No it is not correct.

The definition is that $n$ vectors $v_i\neq 0$ are linearly independent when

$$\sum a_i v_i=0 \iff a_i=0$$

As a consequence we have that

1. $n$ vectors that do not span an $n$ dimensional space are not
   independent
2. if they span an $n$ dimensional space that means they are linearly
   independent

Comment: Yes I understand this statement that if X1, X2,....Xn are independent if no combination give the zero vector (except the zero combination).

Comment: I want to understand it in terms of span

Comment: @AnuragRag That's the definition, from here we can prove the other properties.

Comment: @AnuragRag Note that $n$ linearly independent vectors span an $n$ dimensional space/subspace, that is they form a basis for that space/subspace. Conversely $m>n$ vectors $\in$ to a $n$ dimensional space/subspace are always linearly dependent.

Comment: Is there any intuitive way to verify this statement "n vectors that do not span an n dimensional space are not independent" ?

Comment: @AnuragRag It is simple to understand if you realize that for $n$ linearly independent vectors we can write $w=\sum a_iv_i$ in a unique way, $w$ being a vector $\in$ to the space/subspace spanned.

Comment: @AnuragRag Indeed suppose that $n$ linearly dependent vectors span a $n$ dimensional space then for any $w$ exist $a_i$ such $w=\sum a_iv_i$ but also exist $b_i$ not all zero such that $\sum b_i v_i=0$ then $w=w+0=\sum (a_i+b_i)v_i=\sum c_i v_i$ but that's a contradiction since the representation for $w$ should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Every nonempty set of vectors will span some space.  I think it might help you to focus first on understanding the idea of linear combinations.  All three of the ideas you mentioned depend on that one.

The *span* of your set of vectors is the set of all possible linear combinations of those vectors.

If any one vector in set can be written as a linear combination of the other vectors then the set is *dependent*.  Otherwise it is *independent*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good way to "understand linear dependence in terms of span", if you consider "span" as a black box operation.

You *could* say that a set of vectors is linearly independent if its span has the same *dimension* as the number of vectors you start with -- but the concept of "dimension" itself depends on knowing what linear independence means, so that is not really progress.

Perhaps you could base an understanding of the kind you want to say that linear independence is about *how* the set of vectors generate its span. By definition each element of the span is a linear combination -- but if *every vector in the span has only one linear combination that produces it*, then the set is linearly independent.

It turns out that you don't need to check *every* vector in the span because it can be proved that an *arbitrary* vector in the span has as many linear combinations that produce it as the zero vector has. So it's *enough* to ask whether there is more than one linear combination for the zero vector. And since the trivial linear combination always produces the zero vector, this is the same as asking whether there's any linear combination *other than* the trivial one that produces the zero vector.

Comment: In a span if vector has only one combination they are linearly independent. Else the are dependent. So if they are independent  can  I get my all the Vectors that I started with? And what will happen in case of dependent will I get the less vector?